# Android select install storage on first initialization of application

Tags: android, installation, storage

I'm working on application and I'm curious about one thing : Is there any way I can detect all available storages in phone and let the user select where to install the application on first start. For example :

1. User start application and it's detecting : `Internal Storage - 150MB free, SD Card - 2GB free`
2. If user select SD Card / Internal Storage application is installing on selected device.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound some strange, **After starting application user make a choice where to install application?**

You can't, because for starting application your application need to install on device and you can do only one thing is mentioned in manifest,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         ...
          android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"] >
    . . .
</manifest>
```

**EDIT:**

Prefer  **"auto"**  The application may be installed on the external storage, but the system will install the application on the internal storage by default. If the internal storage is full, then the system will install it on the external storage. Once installed, the user can move the application to either internal or external storage through the system settings.

Comment: Sorry for the explanation...I mean is there any way to ask user before installing the application where to install it..on sd card or internal storage. I've already did this with the manifest file and everything works fine, but I was wondering for the question above. But thanks about the information!

Comment: As per my concern, You can't do it dynamically, the only one things, is after giving  android:installLocation="auto", you can hake the android setting and then from application or via Setting app you can choose the installation location for your application.